# decrease stock quantity at order placement in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, laravel-livewire

I want to decrease quantity from products table when order is added to cart ,right now when I add something to cart, correct quantity is not decreasing. For example if a I place order of 6 items then a random amount gets decreased from my products table.

Here is my code in order controller of livewire:

```
public function IncrementQty($cartId)
{
    $carts=Cart::find($cartId);

    $carts->increment('product_qty',1);
    $updatePrice=$carts->product_qty * $carts->product->price;
    $carts->update(['product_price'=>$updatePrice]);

    $getProductStock=Product::where(['id'=>$carts['product_id']])->first()->toArray();
    $newStock=$getProductStock['quantity'] - $carts['product_qty'];
    Product::where(['id'=>$carts['product_id']])->update(['quantity'=>$newStock]);
    
    $this->mount();
}
```

Being a beginner I am unable to understand about what's wrong here. Should I be substracting it from orderDetails table instead of carts table? If yes then how?

Comment: a cart can only have 1 product in it? ... btw there are `increment` and `decrement` methods for the query builder you could be using instead of doing the math yourself to decrease the quantity

Comment: also i wouldn't be subtracting from 'stock' until the order is actually placed

Comment: no, that 1 is to increase product quantity in cart by one when clicked . Only problem I face right now is random decrease in product stock on order placement .

Comment: What do you mean "*random decrease in product stock on order placement*"? And what does your table-structure look like?

Comment: @Qirel means when for example when I add quantity 3 in cart then 5, 6 or any random quantity gets decreased from products table. My products table contain product_name, quantity, cost, price and alert_stock columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things to note first,

1. You should not call `$this->mount()` or any other lifecycle hooks from Livewire. If there are code inside your mount-method you need to run again, then abstract it into a separate method, and call it from both your `mount()` method and your `IncrementQty()` method.
2. You can use model-route-binding to inject the correct model into the method

   ```php
   public function IncrementQty(Cart $cart)
   ```

You can then simplify your code by using the `product` relation on the cart directly, and calling `decrement()` on that.

```php
public function IncrementQty(Cart $cart)
{
    $product = $cart->product;
    $cart->increment('product_qty', 1);
    $cart->update(['product_price' => $cart->product_qty * $product->price]);

    $product->decrement('quantity', 1);
    
    $this->mount(); // Do not call mount manually, abstract the contents you need into a separate method instead
}
```

If you are still experiencing issues, then it cannot possibly be this piece of code, or you are misreading your data somehow - in any case, if you are still experiencing issues, you will need to provide additional information with your table-structure, models, how you call this method, and data before and after your actions.

Answer (score 0):

it seems you have a problem in this line:

```
$newStock=$getProductStock['quantity'] - $carts['product_qty'];
```

$carts is an object not an array, so, do:

```
$newStock = $getProductStock['quantity'] - $carts->product_qty;
```

Comment: Thanks, but its still decreasing random quantity from stock :(

Comment: if `$carts` is an Eloquent Model it supports array access